# Header is not working and its not showing any errors

Tags: php, html, sql

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Murad'])){header("localtion: http://localhost/murad/centil/o/Main.php");
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$userName=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['pwd1'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "123";
$mysql_databse = "websiteusers";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
$sql = "INSERT INTO websiteusers 
       (fullname,lastname,userName,email,pass) 
       VALUES ( '$firstname', '$lastname','$userName', '$email','$password')";

mysql_select_db('websiteusers');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
  return false;
}echo "Entered data successfully\n";
}
?>
```

There are no include in this file or there is no whitespace,so it is not showing any errors it also inserts data,but it stays on the same page

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL) ;after <?php to ensure there is no error or warning

Comment: `localtion` =/= `Location`

Comment: Fixing the typo I would place the header at the end... right before the if ends. Oh.. and I know this is old.. but mysql_* functions are deprecated. Have a look on mysqli_* or PDO instead.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i know that it just says wait 8 minutes)

Comment: @entiendoNull but mysql_ works.Does it matter?

Comment: @Kolibrok, it "works" for now.. but that mysql library is deprecated, discontinued and will eventually be removed from PHP. So, if you expect your code to be running on a future version of PHP there might be problems. As far as I know the library was discontinued due to security issues among other reasons.

You're better off using mysqli_* or PDO. Have a look on prepared statements. My personal preference is PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header is incorrect, must say:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/murad/centil/o/Main.php");
```